# XSL Transformation with a variable in a XPATH string-comparison

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

simple question but difficult to explain...

I'm inside a node in a xsl transformation. This node has two informations. A country and a year
Outside of this node are lots of other nodes with the same schema. I want all years with the current country.

following sample can contain typos:

```
<prices>
    <price ta:id="RPMA12875162">
        <context>
            <country-ext>US</country-ext>
            <year>2016</year>
        </context>
        <price>
            <value>10</value>
        </price>
    </price>
</prices>
<prices>
    <price ta:id="RPMA12875163">
        <context> <!-- lets say the transformation is here -->
            <country-ext>US</country-ext>
            <year>2014</year>
        </context>
        <price>
            <value>10</value>
        </price>
    </price>
    <price ta:id="RPMA12875162">
        <context>
            <country-ext>DE</country-ext>
            <year>2013</year>
        </context>
        <price>
            <value>9</value>
        </price>
    </price>
    <price ta:id="RPMA12875163">
        <context>
            <country-ext>DE</country-ext>
            <year>2014</year>
        </context>
        <price>
            <value>10</value>
        </price>
    </price>
    <price ta:id="RPMA12875164">
        <context>
            <country-ext>DE</country-ext>
            <year>2015</year>
        </context>
        <price>
            <value>11</value>
        </price>
    </price>
</prices>
```

Following a cleaned xsl

```
<xsl:template match="context">
    <DimensionProperties>
        <xsl:if test="country-ext and year" >
            <xsl:variable name="currentCountryExt1" select="concat(string(country-ext/text()), '')"/>
            <xsl:variable name="currentCountryExt2" select="'US'"/>

            <xsl:variable name="yearOfEepartPrices1" select="../../price/context[string(country-ext/text()) = $currentCountryExt1]/year"/>
            <xsl:variable name="yearOfEepartPrices2" select="../../price/context[string(country-ext/text()) = $currentCountryExt2]/year"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </DimensionProperties>
</xsl:template>
```

while the hardcoded variable currentCountryExt2 works, the currentCountryExt1 does not. While debugging I can see that 1 and 2 are xs:string with the value US.
I tried the same with functions like contains() or without concat(string()). Everytime I get the same result: nothing.

yearOfEepartPrices1 works not

yearOfEepartPrices2 works

any idea?

---

answer to comment:

I concat with '' because I found a hint in a forum where somebody had the same problem like me. He solved this with this little "trick".

I use oXygen as a debugger and the xsl uses later the output where I can verify this misbehavior

Comment: I agree with Ian that you should be using a **key**. That said, I don't understand how did you determine that `$yearOfEepartPrices1` does not work. I believe you are mistaken about that. I suggest you output a `copy-of` of both variables and see that there is no difference between them (as long as the hard-coded country matches the actual value). BTW, why are you concatenating a string (country) with an empty string `''`?

Comment: In response to your edit: "*the xsl uses later the output where I can verify this misbehavior*" We can only go by what you post here. If I remove the undeclared namespace from your input and then copy all your variables into the result tree, there is no difference between the two - see:http://xsltransform.net/nbUY4ko/1

Comment: As you mention oXygen, do you use XSLT 2.0 or 1.0? With XSLT 2.0 it is easy to apply a key only to a subtree e.g. `<xsl:key name="priceByCountry" match="price" use="context/country-ext" />` and `key('priceByCountry', country-ext, ancestor/prices)/context/year`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making things way more complicated than they need to be here.  For the XML structure you've given in the question the following should work fine:

```
<xsl:template match="context">
    <DimensionProperties>
        <xsl:if test="country-ext and year" >
            <xsl:variable name="yearOfEepartPrices"
                  select="../../price/context[
                         country-ext = current()/country-ext]/year"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </DimensionProperties>
</xsl:template>
```

You should avoid using `text()` unless you really need to deal with each individual text node separately - if what you want is the complete string value of a given element then just select the element rather than its set of text node children.

---

*Edit: original question was not clear that there are several separate `prices` nodes, the following suggestion makes sense if you want to find all matching `year` elements in the entire document.*

> I want all years with the current country.

The easiest way to do this is to define a key.

```
<xsl:key name="yearByCountry" match="year" use="../country-ext" />
```

and then you can extract all the `year` elements that match a particular country with

```
key('yearByCountry', $theCountryCode)
```

for example:

```
<xsl:template match="context">
    <DimensionProperties>
        <xsl:if test="country-ext and year" >
            <xsl:variable name="yearOfEepartPrices"
                     select="key('yearByCountry', country-ext)"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </DimensionProperties>
</xsl:template>
```

Or it might make more sense to have the key return `price` elements

```
<xsl:key name="priceByCountry" match="price" use="context/country-ext" />

<xsl:template match="context">
    <DimensionProperties>
        <xsl:if test="country-ext and year" >
            <xsl:variable name="yearOfEepartPrices"
                     select="key('priceByCountry', country-ext)/context/year"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </DimensionProperties>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: hello, whis looks quite good but I forgot to say that prices is not the root. there are lots of prices in the xml. your current key find all